# Android: How to stop emulation

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm coming from Visual studio and C# and am new to Android (and eclipse) so quite ignorant of basic functionality.
I've written a short app and ran it under the emulator. No problems.
Now I've made some changes and want to test them. In VS I'd stop the application debug run before making code changes, and after the code changes run again.

I can't find the 'stop' debug button in eclipse. How do I run my app after I've made changes?

Comment: just run it again from the green play button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is press the [Escape] key on your keyboard or the 'Back' button within the Emulator to close your app then rebuild and run it in Eclipse, which should bring it up as active in the Emulator.

Comment: This mostly works, but sometimes I get an error message. All in all it seems the environment has some niggles, but possible this is because I'm new to it.

Comment: Ah, yeah that happened to me too. It was quite frustrating because the sim/emulator takes quite some time to boot up.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run it again and the code changes will apply.

But else you'll find it under the Debug-window (Window->Show View->Debug) and there is a "terminate" button in the top right corner of your screen.

You might need to close the app inside the emulator though..

Answer (score 1):

There is deference between just running the application and debugging, you can pres play in ellipse and that will run the app but what you can also do is to switch the perspective in debug view (to switch go to the right top corner, and change from java to debug perspective)
in debug mode you can also set break points, just like in visual studio the only difference here is you must change perspective